# How to loop all data in checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

**How to loop all data in checkedlistbox in 'PROPER' way** and print it on console or pop up on messagebox one by one?

I populated my clbPackages this way

```
// clbPackages is a checkedlistbox
SqlCommand scPackages = new SqlCommand("SELECT XXX FROM XXX", sqlConnection);
SqlDataReader readerPackages;
readerPackages = scPackages.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dtPackages = new DataTable();
dtPackages.Columns.Add("PACKAGE_GROUP_ID", typeof(string));
dtPackages.Columns.Add("PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME", typeof(string));
dtPackages.Load(readerPackages);

this.clbPackages.DataSource = dtPackages;
this.clbPackages.ValueMember = "PACKAGE_GROUP_ID";
this.clbPackages.DisplayMember = "PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME";
```

Now I have to loop that checkedlistbox because I am trying to check some in, my best try is this code below

```
foreach (var item in clbPackages.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());               
}
```

It only return xxx.xxx.DataRowView, and if I try to loop again the item it will show error "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' "

---

**answered by Bjorn**

other way to deal

```
foreach (object item in clbPackages.Items)
{     
    DataRowView castedItem = item as DataRowView;
    string groupId= castedItem["PACKAGE_GROUP_ID"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(groupId);
}
```

Comment: `item.ToString()` here will return output like that only since its an object. You need to use that objects properties to get data out of it.

Comment: `foreach (object item in clbPackages.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());               
} `

changed to object and all properties that shows up only toString, Equals and getType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the objects in the Items-collection is of type DataRowView. So if you convert each item to a DataRowView and get the value from that object you should be fine:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in clbPackages.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item["PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME"].ToString());               
}
```

Comment: bingo, thank you..i just realized the @HarveySpecter answer is only about how to deal with the return, but you came first.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you have access to your original data in original:

```
    this.clbPackages.DataSource = dtPackages;
```

So all you have to do is to convert your DataSource to the original items (cast it to DataTable) and you can use all original data, isn't it?

Comment: thankyou, but no i would not use the original to work with, because im trying to revalidate data from original with a new query results..thats why i want to **print it on console one by one**

Comment: Then use the @Björn answer. In the most MVVM (or even MVC pattern) you should operate on model data (here DataSource) and not on View's data.

Answer (score 1):

To loop all data in a checkedListBox control try with this.

```
for(int i=0; i<clbPackages.Items.Count ; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(clbPackages.Items[i].ToString()); 
}
```